# Issue while Submitting module for Magento Marketplace

Tags: magento2, third-party-module, marketplace

I tried to upload my Magento 2 module in Magento Marketplace while uploading the file, there was suddenly error came up and stopped to proceed.

Can anyone help with the error?

```
Environment: PHP 5.6.37 Magento 2.1 EE

./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing <namespace>/module-name (1.1.1): Downloading (connecting...)Downloading (0%)           Downloading (100%)
    proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory
    The archive may contain identical file names with different capitalization (which fails on case insensitive filesystems)
    Unzip with unzip command failed, falling back to ZipArchive class
The following exception is caused by a lack of memory or swap, or not having swap configured
Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#proc-open-fork-failed-errors for details

PHP Warning:  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 959

Warning: proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory in phar:///usr/bin/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php on line 959

  [ErrorException]                                   
  proc_open(): fork failed - Cannot allocate memory  


require [--dev] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--no-update] [--no-scripts] [--update-no-dev] [--update-with-dependencies] [--update-with-all-dependencies] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [--sort-packages] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--] []...
```

Comment: Is it probably magento2 works with php7 ?

Comment: All other environments are passed. Like PHP 7 and Magento 2.3 .. All passed except this case.

Comment: Hi @ShajithaBanu did you got the issue, why its failing?

Comment: I coudn't found the solution to that

Comment: @ShajithaBanu :  is this issue fixed,  i am also getting same issue. can you please update.what we need to do.